# DataInputStream strange behaviour

Tags: java, datainputstream

I would like to build an hashmap from a binary file. This binary file has the following structure: the first integer indicates the number of integers that I have to read from the stream in order to build the hashmap followed by the key/value pairs.

So for an hashmap with three values I would have a total of 7 Integers:

1 int to read - 2 key - 3 value - 4 key - 5 value - 6 key - 7 value

How is it possible that the two following codes have two different outcomes? The only difference is that in the first example I use an auxiliary variable **a** to store the value of bytes to read. In the second one I just use it directly in the for loop.

```
static Int2IntMap fetchHashMap(Int2IntMap map, DataInputStream DIS) throws IOException {
    int a = DIS.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        map.put(DIS.readInt(),DIS.readInt());
    }
    return map;
}
```

This is the code without auxiliary variable:

```
static Int2IntMap fetchHashMap(Int2IntMap map, DataInputStream DIS) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIS.readInt(); i++) {
        map.put(DIS.readInt(),DIS.readInt());
    }
    return map;
}
```

The former works better than the latter but it is still inconsistent with the structure I would expect.

I do not know if it is relevant but my implementation uses multi-threading,  but each thread has its own DataInputStream.

Comment: Regarding your threading with each thread having its own `DataInputStream`, does each of those read from its own file too?

Comment: yes, each thread has it own file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire condition of a `for` loop is executed before every iteration. In your second method, `i < DIS.readInt();` runs before *each* iteration, reading a new `int` from `DIS`. Your first method does it the correct way, by only reading once and caching the value.